# Three.js Hemisphere Light

Tags: three.js

I`m examining a different types of light with dat.GUI and three.js (r72) and get stucked on dinamically turning on/off the HemisphereLight.
I have a one instance of each light being added to the scene:

```
var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(this._whiteColor);
pointLight.visible = false;

var hemisphereLight = new THREE.HemisphereLight(this._whiteColor, this._whiteColor);
hemisphereLight.visible = false;
```

ect...

and a buttons for turning on/off with simple handler. Like this:

```
me._sceneObjects.hemisphereLight.visible = value;
```

So, before rendering all lights are present in the scene, but not visible.
When executing a handler for Hemisphere light - it stay invisible. After excluding hemisphereLight.visible = false; works fine.

Currently I`m disabling this light after rendering a 1st frame:

```
function render() {
    some code ...

    if (!sentenceExecuted && firstCall > 0) {
        hemisphereLight.light.visible = false;
        sentenceExecuted = true;
    } else {
        firstCall++;
    }
};
```

I will be grateful for any suggestions to fix this without workaround.
Sorry for possible mistakes in English.

Comment: 1. You code fragments do not make it clear what the problem is. Can you show a live example? 2. The Wiki article [How to Update Things with WebGLRenderer](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Updates) may help. 3. The problem is likely not specific to HemisphereLight.

Comment: Example on codepen
http://codepen.io/majeretft/pen/RWRjjB
Currently faced another problem. I think both are relative to a single mistake (should call a function to force render to recalc some data, but cant find what i have missed)

Comment: 1. Seriously, you must say what the problem is. 2. Start with `light.visible` = `true` and your code appears to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WestLangley, thank you for the link to [Wiki article](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Updates).

After reading and trying the examples I have found my mistake.
Originally I wanted to add "invisible" (using Object3D.visible) for render lights into a scene and then turn them on/off dynamically.

Some lights (in my case HemisphereLight and SpotLight) do not work this way because of internal three.js rendering algorythm (buffers for geometries and materials were built without considering my lights).

To achieve dynamic lightning an author of the article suggest to:

1. Add light with intensity = 0 and then increase it (such light is taken into account by render)
2. Force material to be updated (material.needsUpdate = true) for affected scene objects after setting light visibility to true.